# Designing a differential equation circuit with op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, integrator

I have the following assignment question

[image]

The differential terms all contain the output voltage in differential forms. My first thought was to then implement op-amp as integrators in each stage since Vx would be related to an integral form of Vin, but I am still stuck. I get that the output of the first op-amp will produce a first degree differential term as the output which if we connect to the second op-amp, we'll get a 2nd degree differential term. I am not sure however, if this is the right way.

Also, how do I get the bVx term here? For the cVi term, it would be a simple scaling factor c, which can just be a simple voltage amplifier. But how do I get the LHS in this equation? Help appreciated, thanks

Comment: State variable biquad filter may work.

Answer (score 0):

As example, here is a Van der Pol oscillator.

[image]